# Cannot pgrep the pid of tmux with -x option on Debian(bullseye)

Tags: linux, debian, tmux

I'm writing a script in which a function needs to retrieve the pid of tmux server.

```
tmux_pid=$(pgrep tmux)
```

However the script name contains tmux, e.g. tmux-launcher, when running it, pgrep returns two pids, one is for tmux, the other is for the running script itself. I tried to use `pgrep -x tmux` to match the exact server process, but none pid returned.

Here is the `htop` output for the tmux server

```
PID  USER      PRI  NI  VIRT   RES   SHR S CPU%▽MEM%   TIME+  Command
2991 xxxxx      20   0 15336  3800  2924 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.03 tmux new -d -s se..
```

To verify `-x` option of `pgrep`, I also did a test with two scripts `yyy` and `yyy-abc`, which shows `-x` works well.

yyy:

```
#!/bin/sh  
sleep 60
```

yyy-abc:

```
#!/bin/sh
pid=$(pgrep -x yyy)
echo $pid
sleep 30
```

Test:

```
➜  ~ ./yyy &
[2] 9219
➜  ~ ./yyy-abc
9219
```

So why `pgrep -x tmux` shows nothing? Is it a tmux's problem or pgrep's problem?

BTW, on macOS, this shows the exact tmux's pid.

Comment: Ask the tmux server itself: `tmux display-message -p '#{pid}'`

Comment: Many thanks @KamilMaciorowski, though my OP was not answered, you gave me a nice and straight solution to get server pid, which is what I really need. 
After some more tests, I'm aware that even `-x tmux` works well, there could be multiple processes with command named exact `tmux`. If press `m` in `htop`, it will show multiple `tmux│tmux: client` and one `tmux│tmux: server`, so use `pgrep` is not a decent solution at all.

Comment: Still, `pgrep -xo tmux` should find the top level (oldest) tmux, but I agree, it doesn't match for some reason on Ubuntu either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran across this as well on Ubuntu under WSL.

[This Unix & Linux answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/267021/432493) helped point me in the right direction.  `-x` matches on the process *name* from `/etc/<PID>/status`.  That's the same thing you see in `htop` (e.g. `tmux: server`).

`-xf`, on the other hand, matches exactly on the "full command line" (`/proc/PID/cmdline`).

Oddly, with tmux, the "full command line" is the truncated form of the process name, rather than the other way around.

So we have a few options to get find tmux PIDs using `pgrep`.  Note for macOS users that (per @gpanda's comment below) these aren't likely to work there -- Check the "alternative" below:

| Command | Result |
| --- | --- |
| `pgrep -xo "tmux: server"` | Returns the PID of the tmux server |
| `pgrep -xo "tmux: client"` | Returns the PID of the tmux client |
| `pgrep -xof tmux` | Returns the oldest tmux instance created. On my system, this is the client, but this may be timing-dependent. |
| `pgrep -xnf tmux` | Returns the newest tmux instance created. On my system, this is the server, but ... ditto. |

---

###### Alternative

Also, to recap the solution from the comments, as part of an answer so that readers don't have to scour the comments looking for it, an (apparently good cross-platform) alternative provided by @KamilMaciorowski is to have tmux report its own PID via:

```
tmux display-message -p '#{pid}'
```

Comment: Thanks @NotTheDr01ds, it works like a charm. Since the OP is about Debian, I accept the answer. By the way, this doesn't work on macOS from my test, I guess it's because there is no `tmux: server` nor `tmux: client` fields in command name. (I toggled merged command by type `m` in htop to check `tmux: server` or `tmux: client`). `tmux display-message -p '#{pid}'` works on both platforms because it asks the tmux server directly.

Comment: Thanks @gpanda - Good info!  I'll add the info on macOS to the answer as well.